# Sharing data between threads, getting error "value moved into closure here, in previous iteration of loop"

Tags: multithreading, rust, websocket, thread-safety

The aim of the following programm is to make a websocket server that listen HTTP request on a separate http-server and send the request into a string to the websocket-client.

The websocket client is done and works perfectly, but I have this little error on the websocket-server when I'm trying to pass my HTTP Request (in the `http_listener` thread) which is a String to the websocket-canal thread.

```rust
extern crate websocket;

use std::io::{Read, Write};
use std::net::{TcpListener, TcpStream};
use std::sync::mpsc;
use std::sync::Arc;
use std::sync::Mutex;
use std::thread;
use websocket::sync::Server;
use websocket::OwnedMessage;

use actix_web::{web, App, Error, HttpRequest, HttpResponse, HttpServer};

fn main() -> std::io::Result<()> {
    let (tx, rx) = mpsc::channel();

    //let shared_request = Arc::new(Mutex::new(String::new()));

    let websocket_server = thread::spawn(move || {
        let server = Server::bind("127.0.0.1:1234").unwrap();
        println!("Websocket server listening on port 1234");

        for request in server.filter_map(Result::ok) {
            // Spawn a new thread for each connection.
            let tx = tx.clone();

            let websocket_canal = thread::spawn(move || {
                if !request.protocols().contains(&"rust-websocket".to_string()) {
                    request.reject().unwrap();
                    return;
                }

                let mut client = request.use_protocol("rust-websocket").accept().unwrap();

                let ip = client.peer_addr().unwrap();

                println!("Connection from {}", ip);

                let message = OwnedMessage::Text("Hello".to_string());
                client.send_message(&message).unwrap();

                let received_message = rx.recv().unwrap();
                println!("requête from thread http server:\n{}", received_message);

                //let final_string = shared_request.lock().unwrap();
                //println!("requête from thread http server:\n{}", *final_string);

                let (mut receiver, mut sender) = client.split().unwrap();

                for message in receiver.incoming_messages() {
                    let message = message.unwrap();

                    match message {
                        OwnedMessage::Close(_) => {
                            let message = OwnedMessage::Close(None);
                            sender.send_message(&message).unwrap();
                            println!("Client {} disconnected", ip);
                            return;
                        }
                        OwnedMessage::Ping(ping) => {
                            let message = OwnedMessage::Pong(ping);
                            sender.send_message(&message).unwrap();
                        }
                        _ => sender.send_message(&message).unwrap(),
                    }
                }
            });

            let http_listener = thread::spawn(move || {
                let listener = TcpListener::bind("127.0.0.1:8080").unwrap();
                println!("Websocket server listening on port 8080");

                for stream in listener.incoming() {
                    match stream {
                        Ok(mut stream) => {
                            let mut buffer = [0; 1024];
                            stream.read(&mut buffer).unwrap();
                            let request = String::from_utf8_lossy(&buffer).to_string();

                            println!("Received request:\n{}", request);
                            let txmessage = request.clone();
                            tx.send(txmessage).unwrap();

                            //let mut data = shared_request.lock().unwrap();
                            //data.push_str(&request);

                            let response = "HTTP/1.1 200 OK\r\n\r\nHello, World!\n";
                            stream.write(response.as_bytes()).unwrap();
                        }
                        Err(e) => {
                            eprintln!("Error: {}", e);
                        }
                    }
                }
            });

            websocket_canal.join().unwrap();
            http_listener.join().unwrap();
        }
    });

    websocket_server.join().unwrap();

    Ok(())
}
```

```
error[E0382]: use of moved value: `rx`
  --> src/ws-server2.rs:29:38
   |
29 |             let websocket_canal=thread::spawn(move || {
   |                                               ^^^^^^^ value moved into closure here, in previous iteration of loop
...
45 |                 let received_message = rx.recv().unwrap();
   |                                        -- use occurs due to use in closure
   |
   = note: move occurs because `rx` has type `std::sync::mpsc::Receiver<String>`, which does not implement the `Copy` trait
```

I know what the problem is but I don't succeed in solving it, I have tried using `Arc`, `Mutex`, every combination of `tx`, `rx` etc...

But nothing I tried works and this is the code that has the fewest errors.

Comment: Have you tried wrapping `rx` in an `Arc<Mutex<_>>` and cloning the `Arc`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of using a `mpsc` which stands for multiple producer **single** consumer you want to use a channel that can handle multiple consumers because that's how you use it.
I suggest using `crossbeam_channel` since [that's the implementation `std` uses internally for its `mpsc`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/src/std/sync/mpsc/mod.rs.html#146-149) so you can pretty much drop in replace it:

```
  fn main() -> std::io::Result<()> {
-     let (tx, rx) = mpsc::channel();
+     let (tx, rx) = crossbeam_channel::unbounded();
```

```
              let tx = tx.clone();
+             let rx = rx.clone();

              let websocket_canal = thread::spawn(move || {
```